# How to make specific part of image as background Image?

Tags: image, flutter

How can I make the selected part in the image below as my background image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `alignment` property of `Image` or `DecorationImage` combined with `fit`.

```
Image.network(
  'url',
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
);
```